# unzip the url and sending and receiving the data from server

Tags: objective-c

I am having an zip url like @"http://1.18.10.14/something.zip" now i want to unzip this url and have to send request to server and access the data and should store that data locally...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive). You can download your data with [`dataWithContentsOfURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL%3a) and save to zip-file with [`writeToFile:atomically:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a).